# Saracen Tenet 2 suitable for long distance

Tags: road-bike

I've got some outings coming up which will need a few days of 100 mile bike rides, this isn't something I'm going to do all the time but I'd like to the option to. I've been looking at road bikes and tried a Saracen Tenet 2 2014 at my local bike shop.

I really like it but I'm not really sure looking at the specs if it will be up to the work? I do really like it but I don't have much experience this area.

Here is the spec list:-

http://www.evanscycles.com/products/saracen/tenet-2-2014-road-bike-ec060482

Something's which I've noticed:

- doesnt have disc brakes, is this a big deal?
- sora gears set seem to be well reviewed
- carbon fork keeps this bike light?

Any help people can give me in the right direction would, be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your link doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bike should be perfectly fine for 100 mile ride, specs look similar to other products in this price range. I'd rather bother myself with fit and comfort, these will mean more on long distance ride, ask LBS for a test ride.

> doesnt have disc brakes, is this a big deal?

If you are not going to descend mountains or ride in very wet conditions, then no. People are riding without disc brakes for years, it's just another option.

> sora gears set seem to be well reviewed

Sora should do the shifting alright.

> carbon fork keeps this bike light?

Not exactly, aluminium forks are about 200 grams heavier than carbon fiber, which isn't big deal, given the bike weight almost 10kg. It should be somewhat more comfortable, though.